# find list of colors in mplfinance for seq_col to draw lines

Tags: python, mplfinance

Can't find anything in the dokumentation:
https://pypi.org/project/mplfinance/

Need to draw lines in different colors, found just theese color codes:

```
'b','r','c','k','g'
```

A few more colors would be great - didn't find a list in the documentation.

The best would be if someone could specify the rgb code.

I mean e.g. this line:
[image]

the plot:

```
    mpf.plot(df_history, show_nontrading=True, figratio=(10,7), figscale=2, datetime_format='%d.%m.%y', #figscale=2
             xrotation=90, tight_layout=False, xlim=(xmin, xmax), ylim=(chart_unten, chart_oben),
             alines=dict(alines=seq_of_points, colors=seq_of_colors, linestyle='-', linewidths=1),
             type='candle', savefig=bildpfad, addplot=apdict, style=s, title=chart_title,
             update_width_config=dict(candle_linewidth=0.5))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sample in the official reference, I wrote the code to customize the Seaborn using its color. The [official reference](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/using_lines.ipynb) can be found here, and since the hex format is supported, various approaches are possible.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import seaborn as sns
import mplfinance as mpf

color_palette = sns.color_palette("husl", 3)
colors = [mcolors.to_hex(c) for c in color_palette] 

df = pd.read_csv('./data/yahoofinance-SPY-20080101-20180101.csv',index_col=0,parse_dates=True)
df = df.loc['2016-05-01':'2016-06-16',:]

seq_of_seq_repeat_point_in_between=[
    [('2016-05-02',207),('2016-05-06',204)],
    [('2016-05-06',204),('2016-05-10',208.5),('2016-05-19',203.5),('2016-05-25',209.5)],
    [('2016-05-25',209.5),('2016-06-08',212),('2016-06-16',207.5)]]
    
mpf.plot(df,
         type='candle',style='charles',
         alines=dict(alines=seq_of_seq_repeat_point_in_between,
                     colors=colors,
                     linewidths=4,
                     alpha=0.7),
         figscale=1.25
        )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np

colors = cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, arr.shape[0]))
plt.scatter(arr, arr, c=colors)
```

[image]

In your case:

```
import matplotlib.cm as cm

seq_of_colors = cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, df_history.shape[0]))
```

Comment: Thanks very much for you answer, I ment the lines, not the chart. I add a pic